# ExtJS4.1 Grid update: Changes are not reflected immediately. Need to search again to see the updated values in IE9

Tags: extjs

I am new to Extjs4.1. I need to edit the grid data cell and edited value saved while pressing save button in grid toolbar. Its working nice. But changes are not reflected immediately. 
   When I press save button, the updated cell having old value. I need to click search button to see updated values.

I called `store.load();` inside the saveFunction() and I can able to store edited values in DB. But the Grid is not displaying the updated values immediately in IE9.

Please someone help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: does it work in IE8 or FF or Chrome?

Comment: Hi DmitryB, I have tested on Chrome 21.0.1180.83 and FF 14.0.1. What happened is, if i run at first time the changes are't reflected immediately and after that if i made any changes then its immediately reflected in both FF & Chrome. I did check with IE8. Whereas in IE9 every time I need to search for updated values after saving.

Comment: And it is applicable to all like adding new record & deleting record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally got the ans. I just loaded the store in ajax success 
`success: function(response, options) {                                          store.load(); }`.

Thanks all.